# fabric-ca request register failed | fabric-samples release-1.4 | balance-transfer network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to set up [balance-transfer hyperledger fabric network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer). I have followed the steps in the [README.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/README.md). While running `./runApp.sh`, I got the following error.

```
Creating network "artifacts_default" with the default driver
Pulling ca.org1.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-ca:)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

After googling the following steps, resolved the issue.

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-preview 
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-preview hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0-preview 
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0-preview hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0-preview
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0-preview hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```

After this steps `./runApp.sh` command is success. While running `./testAPIs.sh -l golang`, I am getting the following error in REST Server.

```
[2020-08-25 09:08:41.463] [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: Barry with error: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]
[2020-08-25 09:08:41.463] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - -- returned from registering the username Barry for organization Org2
[2020-08-25 09:08:41.463] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - Failed to register the username Barry for organization Org2 with::failed Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]
UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed
    at /var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:102:22
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:63:12)
    at verifyToken (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:100:13)
    at fn (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
    at /var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
    at /var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
    at /var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
```

I am getting the following error in fabric-ca.

```
2020/08/25 09:08:41 [INFO] 172.29.0.1:57476 POST /api/v1/enroll 200 0 "OK"
2020/08/25 09:08:41 [DEBUG] Received request for /api/v1/register
2020/08/25 09:08:41 [DEBUG] Received registration request from : { Name:Barry Type: Secret:**** MaxEnrollments:1 Affiliation:org2.department1 Attributes:[] CAName:ca-org2  }
2020/08/25 09:08:41 [DEBUG] Sent error for /api/v1/register: scode: 401, local code: 25, local msg: Invalid token in authorization header: Token signature validation failed, remote code: 20, remote msg: Authorization failure

github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.newAuthErr
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/servererror.go:145
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*serverRequestContext).TokenAuthentication
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverrequestcontext.go:129
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.registerHandler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverregister.go:49
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*serverEndpoint).ServeHTTP
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverendpoint.go:44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2254
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2619
net/http.(*conn).serve
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
2020/08/25 09:08:41 [INFO] 172.29.0.1:57480 POST /api/v1/register 401 25 "Invalid token in authorization header: Token signature validation failed"
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Any specific reason for using `fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-preview` ? Isn't it too old fabric version ? You can use `fabric-ca:1.4.8`. This is the latest `ca` version. It works with both `fabricv2.x` and `fabricv1.4.x`.

Comment: I am not aware of versioning things. I googled the error `https://www.edureka.co/community/30239/hyperledger-fabric-error-manifest-hyperledger-fabric-latest ` . This is the solution I got. Now It is working after replacing 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues with your question here:

1. you are using a 3 years old `hyperledger-fabric` version. But in the question you have mentioned that you are using `v1.4`. check [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags?page=1&name=x86_64-1.1.0-preview) your version info.
2. You can use tag `1.4.8` for `ca`, `peer`,`orderer` instead of `x86_64-1.1.0-preview`.
3. `latest` tag is misleading because now there are two hyperledger-fabric versions i.e `fabric:v2.x` and `fabric:v1.4.x`. hence better approach is to use specific tag instead of `latest`.